# Open new child form from onother child Form By Button Click Event Windows application c#

Tags: c#

Sir, I have One MDI form and Two Child form Form1 and Form2 in Windows application C#.net,And I want to go to Form2 By the button Click event Of Button of Form1 and Form2 must be Open in the MDI Conainer 
Plese send me a solution....
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Get Form1 to tell its parent to create or go to Form2. If it needs information from Form1 you'll need to send that along with the request or keep the information globally (e.g. static field).